# Monoprice MP Mini Delta adding glass bed

Tags: g-code, monoprice-mini-delta, automatic-bed-leveling

The bed adhesion is going from already mediocre to unusable. So I got my glass plate. With my previous printer I really liked printing PLA on a 60 °C alcohol-cleaned bed.

The problem that I am having, is that the auto-leveling procedure fails. The bed sensors are detected 3 mm (glass height) sooner than it anticipates.

Customer support told me that I can alter this in the slicer settings. "It can be done in CURA or whatever slicer I am using".

I am using that Wiibuilder program that was supplied with the printer on the SD card. I may or may not have searched hard enough, but I haven't found it.  I did find this

[image: Screenshot of Wiibuilder's Warping Precaution settings]

Only it does not do anything. The auto-leveling still fails.

Customer support also told me I can just alter the G-code. They neglect to mention how to do so.

This seems to be the starting part.

```
M73 P0
;MINX:-9.0
;MAXX:12.0
;MINY:-26.0
;MAXY:25.0
;MINZ:0.0
;MAXZ:26.3
;MachineType:MP Mini Delta V2
;FilamentType:PLA
;Extruder0Temperature:200
;BedTemperature:55
;InfillDensity:10
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:1372
;FilamentUsed:1557.2
;Layer height: 0.35

;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 3.1
M140 S55
M104 T0 S215
M82 ; absolute extrusion mode
;(**** start.gcode for MP Mini Delta****)
G21
G90
M82
M107
M104 S170
G28 X0 Y0
G28 Z0
G29 Z0.4
G1 Z15 F300
M109 S215.0
G92 E0
G1 F200 E3
G92 E0
G1 F2000
```

Can somebody tell me what I must alter or add here to let the printer auto-level with the 3 mm glass bed?

I tried setting `G29` on  `3.4` no effect.
I tried setting `G29` on `-2.6` no effect.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried setting G29 on 3.4 no effect. I tried setting G29 on -2.6 no effect."? How do you exactly do it? Have you modified Z-offset value in your printer or in Cura? What is your Z-offset value from printer's screen?

Comment: What I mean is that I tried to manually edit the G-code line containing G29

Comment: Note that `G28 Z0` is not valid, `G28 Z` is so is `G28 X0 Y0`, the letters are flags, the number is ignored. Unless your firmware is MachineKit, `G29 Z0.4` doesn't do anything.

Comment: What happens when you add `M851 Z-2.6` to your G-code? It should set Z-offset value to `-2.6`.

Comment: I will try that tonight after work. I'll get back to you

Comment: @0scar If it does not do anything than why would my slicer put it there?

Comment: Because it is in the start G-code, that has been put there by someone, not by Cura. Presumably by some config?

Comment: @kosteklvp I tried M851 Z-2.6, no effect. I am going to mail customer support again.

Comment: Also that Z-axis offset you can fill in in Wiibuilder results in this line `G92 Z3.27`.. it unfortunately does not help though